# Incorrect result from element value comparison

Tags: javascript, html, comparison

I'm making an `html` card game and it has an `if` statement with a greater than or equal to comparison operator. But when the money is lower that the price it still runs as if you have the needed money.

**HTML**

```
    <article id="moneysys">
        <p id="ptdabtd" >Click 'Set Cash' To Enter A Starting Ammount. (Button Will Be Deleted Once Finished)</p>
        <button id="scda" onclick="setcash();">Set Cash.</button>
        <br />
        <div class="cash">Cash: <span id="cash">0</span></div>
        <div>Pack Price: <span id="packprice">50</span></div>
    </article>
    <main>
        <center>
            <button class="open" onclick="opencards()">Open Cards.</button>
            <br />
            <img class="card" src="images/blank.png" id="canvas" />
            <img class="card" src="images/blank.png" id="canvas1" />
            <img class="card" src="images/blank.png" id="canvas2" />
            <img class="card" src="images/blank.png" id="canvas3" />
            <img class="card" src="images/blank.png" id="canvas4" />
        </center>
    </main>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function setcash(){
    var wcash =  prompt("Please Enter How Much Cash You Want To Start With", "Cash Wanted");
    document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML = wcash;
    document.getElementById("scda").remove();
    document.getElementById("ptdabtd").remove();

}

var cards = new Array("images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png", "images/4.png", "images/5.png","images/6.png", "images/7.png", "images/8.png", "images/9.png");

var pack = document.getElementById("packprice");
var ccash = document.getElementById("cash");

var pc = Number(pack);
var cash = Number(ccash);

function opencards(){
    if (cash >= pc){
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
        document.getElementById("canvas").src = cards[randomNum];
        document.getElementById("canvas1").src = cards[randomNum];
        document.getElementById("canvas2").src = cards[randomNum];
        document.getElementById("canvas3").src = cards[randomNum];
        document.getElementById("canvas4").src = cards[randomNum];
        cash = cash - pc;
    } else{
        alert("not")
    }
};
```

Comment: you are not getting values? what is  `Number(pack)`? pack is a `html element`

Comment: Well it's supposed to compare the two values from the HTML code but it just ignores that when I run it.

Comment: You are converting DOM-Elements to numbers. Access the inside text of the elements with `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only getting the element itself, but not the actual value of those. You are then trying to get a number from an element. Since the actual elements don't change (regardless of what the innerhtml is set to) you're getting the same result every time in the comparison.

```
var pack = document.getElementById("packprice"); //this gets you the element
var ccash = document.getElementById("cash"); //this gets you the element
```

Try instead:

```
var pack = document.getElementById("packprice").innerHTML;
var ccash = document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML;
```

You can probably also omit

```
var pc = Number(pack);
var cash = Number(ccash);
```

Comment: This does work, so now it will display not if it's lower than 50. However, it no longer shows any of the cards. Any ideas?

Comment: @MorganClarke use browser console to see errors and debug your code

Comment: @FastSnail Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null this was in console

Comment: @MorganClarke you should execute this codes after dom is loaded.basically error says element doesn't exist

Comment: Yes, I have put the .innerHTML; parts inside the function so the variables are read after they user has set them. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are not getting the value of `pack` or `ccash` variable. Because you not use the **innerHTML** .

The innerHTML property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element.

```
var pack = document.getElementById("packprice");
var ccash = document.getElementById("cash");
```

Replace your code with this

```
var pack = document.getElementById("packprice").innerHTML;
var ccash = document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML;
```

[Refrence](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjssant67rMAhVCkI4KHTFKDd8QFggoMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FElement%2FinnerHTML&usg=AFQjCNF4R8v2uvjMHLtHGQ5Qj42jZkzM_A&sig2=xVJ57BlXRHaRSTqwKdK7XQ&cad=rja)

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like :

```
console.log('typeOf Cash : ' + typeof cash + ', cash value : ' + cash);
console.log('typeOf pc : ' + typeof pc + ', pc value : ' + pc);
```

Just before the if statement, please.

Comment: Just ignore it, somebody gives many clues during the write of this post.